# Trying to get property 'page' of non-object while using session variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to put `$request` in the session variable but when I try to get in the controller its showing error `Trying to get property 'page' of non-object`.

code below

```
Session::put('request', $request->all());

if ($request->page == null) {
    Session::put('key', $request->all());
}
```

Comment: It's important to include the framework in your question description for quicker understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not from session. the error  on this line `if ($request->page == null)`.

The `$request->page` variable you're trying to access is not defined.

Try to check empty condition it will check variable is isset or null as well.

```
if (empty($request->page)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check  `empty` condition insted of `NULL`

```
if (empty($request->page)) {
  Session::put('key', $request->all());
}
```